# useState() hook removes fields from the object when setting new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can't understand what I'm doing wrong here. I have a very simple object state:

```
const [itemInput, setItemInput] = useState({
    userId: userId,
    objectId: id,
    title: "",
    description: "",
    createdAt: new Date().getTime().toString(),
  })
```

Then, I have an input that changes the `title` field:

```
const onChange = (e) => {
    setItemInput((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };
```

And this is how `onChange` is used:

```
<input
        type="text"
        className="item-description-input"
        placeholder="Add description..."
        name="title"
        value={itemInput.title}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
```

GraphQL endpoint:

```
export const CREATE_ITEM = gql`
  mutation createItem($itemInput: ItemInput!) {
    createItem(itemInput: $itemInput) {
      userId
      objectId
      title
      description
      createdAt
    }
  }
`;
```

Submit function:

```
const onAddItemClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createItem({
      variables: {
        itemInput: itemInput,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  };
```

When submitting, I get:

```
message: "Variable "$itemInput" got invalid value { title: "ddd" }; Field "userId" of required type "MongoId!" was not provided."
```

And this error is repeated for all the remaining fields but `title`.

If I `console.log(itemInput)` when the functional component is loaded, I get the initial state of the object. However if I add `console.log(itemInput)` after `onChange`, I get only `{title: "some_added_text"}`. onChange removes the other fields from the object, and, on submit, my graphQL endpoint returns an error that the other fields are not provided. This is very frustrating, as I seem to be doing everything correctly.

UPD: Added the components. `Object` component gets the list of objects. Each `Object` has `Items`. The problematic code is in the `Items` component when I want to add a new `Item` to that `Object`.

**Object (parent) component:**

```
import React, { useState, useReactiveVar, Fragment } from "react";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import CREATE_OBJECT from "../../mutations/Object";
import { objectsVar } from "../../cache";

//Components
import ItemContainer from "./ItemContainer";

const Container = ({ data, userId, color }) => {
  const [objectInput, setobjectInput] = useState({
    title: "",
    userId: userId,
    createdAt: new Date().getTime().toString(),
    color: color,
  });

  const [createObject] = useMutation(CREATE_OBJECT);

  const onAddClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createObject({
      variables: {
        objectInput: objectInput,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      setobjectInput({
        title: "",
        userId: userId,
        createdAt: new Date().getTime().toString(),
        color: color,
      });
    });
  };
  
  // This works perfectly fine!! 
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setobjectInput({ ...objectInput, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  objectsVar(data);
  const objects = useReactiveVar(objectsVar);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add description..."
          name="title"
          value={objectInput.title}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div onClick={onAddClick}>Add object</div>
      {objects && objects.getAllObjects.length === 0 ? (
        <p>No objects</p>
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          {objects &&
            objects.getAllActiveSwimlines.map(({ _id, title, items }) => (
              <ItemContainer key={_id} id={_id} title={title} userId={userId} items={items} />
            ))}
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

**Item (child) component:**

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import ItemContainer from "../Item/ItemContainer";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { CREATE_ITEM } from "../../mutations/Item";

const ItemContainer = ({ id, title, items, userId }) => {
  const [itemInput, setItemInput] = useState({
    userId: userId,
    objectId: id,
    title: "initial state",
    description: "test desc",
    createdAt: new Date().getTime().toString(),
  });

  // This doesn't work!
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setItemInput({
      ...itemInput,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const [createItem] = useMutation(CREATE_ITEM);

  const onAddItemClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    createItem({
      variables: {
        itemInput: itemInput,
      },
    }).then((res) => {
      setItemInput({
        userId: userId,
        objectId: id,
        title: "",
        description: "",
        createdAt: new Date().getTime().toString(),
      });

      console.log(res);
    });
  };

  const newItemInput = (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add description..."
        name="title"
        value={itemInput.title}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
      <div onClick={onAddItemClick}>Add item</div>
    </div>
  );

  const itemContent = (
    <div>
      <Fragment>
        {items &&
          items.getObjectItems.map(({ _id, title }) => (
            <Item key={_id} id={_id} title={title} />
          ))}
      </Fragment>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {newItemInput}
      {itemContent}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ItemContainer;
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Showing an entire component and how these functions are used within it will give some valuable insight to those trying to solve your problem. Also, if you use eslint I highly suggest installing [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) which might reveal your problem right away, as it sounds like you just have a missing dependency somewhere.

Comment: Additionally to @PatrickRoberts: Your example works just fine:  https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-pare-ky76p?file=/src/App.tsx   (btw: you should use `currentTarget` instead of `target`).  Could you provide a real example?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Added the components

Comment: setItemInput({
      ...itemInput,
      [name]: value,
    }); is not using the correct pattern to update the state based on the previous state. Can you try using the idiomatic version setItemInput(prev => ...)? (sorry for brevity, not at a computer right now)

Comment: @DanBurzo that was the initial code that didn't work too.

Comment: The state part seems fine, so the problem must be elsewhere. If you can make a StackBlitz/CodeSandbox example that has the problem we might be able to do more. The GraphQL code won't need to be in there. I also notice a strange `import ItemContainer from "../Item/ItemContainer";` in your `ItemContainer` file. Maybe there are multiple copies?

Comment: I accepted @Oblosys answer below. Turned out I was setting the state somewhere else as well... So much time wasted on a stupid bug. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you access `e.target.name` and `e.target.value` inside your update function, they don't get evaluated immediately, and by the the time they do, the synthetic event object has been reused. If you want to keep the rest of the code as it is, you can fix it by calling `e.persist()` at the start of `onChange`, or copy the relevant information from the event:

```
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target
    setItemInput((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };
```

Alternatively, you can let go of the update function and just set the state directly, (which was also suggested in the other answer that got deleted):

```
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setItemInput({
      ...itemInput,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added e.persist() before const{name, value}, and still the same result. Tried without e.persist() with your code, and still no luck.

Comment: Note that this answer will no longer apply in React >= v17 as they've [removed event pooling](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1700-october-20-2020).

Comment: I'm using 17.0.1. And both of the versions of @oblosys produce the same result. The thing is that that same code works in the parent component, I'm really puzzled.

Comment: Good point, the problem won't happen anymore then. There may be something else going on though, if neither solution fixes the original problem.

Comment: Hard to say what the problem could be without seeing the entire component (preferably stripped down). For tinkering with the component, it may be helpful to include `{JSON.stringify(itemInput)}` to the rendering, so you can easily see the state.

Comment: JSON.stringify(itemInput) shows the initial state perfectly when I log, and then again shows {title: "some_value"} when I type the title in the input.